# Unable to access "Users and Groups" in Plone 4

Tags: plone, usergroups

Whenever I try to access "User and Groups" in Plone Site Setup, I'm getting the following error :

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module plone.app.controlpanel.usergroups, line 211, in __call__
  Module plone.app.controlpanel.usergroups, line 270, in doSearch
KeyError: 'adminusername'
```

This plone instance has previously been upgraded from Plone 3 to Plone 4. Users and Groups used to work. A new blank Plone instance created in the same Zope allows access to Users and Groups.

Versions used are :

Plone 4.0.7
Zope 2.12.18
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Nov 23 2010, 02:02:03) [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)]

Answer (score 1):

Check your logs very carefully.  I'm doing a lot of work with PAS plugins right now, and I'm seeing similar sorts of errors when adapters/subscribers are misconfigured, but the errors they generate are masked by the form error above.  Look at the error immediately *before* this one.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no other recent errors either in the plone error log (under site setup), or in instance.log.